# Teradata create query failed with Error 3706 expected something between ')' and '.'

Tags: sql, syntax, syntax-error, teradata, create-table

My below table create query failed:

```
create table db_name.table_name
(col1 BIGINT,
col2 BIGINT,
col3 VARCHAR(50),
col4 VARCHAR(2),
col5 VARCHAR(3),
col6 VARCHAR(1),
col7 BIGINT,
col8 BIGINT
)
```

with the error:

```
.LABEL QUIT_OUT
.EXIT ERRORCODE;

.LABEL QUIT_OUT
  $
 *** Failure 3706 Syntax error: expected something between ')' and '.'.
                Statement# 1, Info =231
```

Can someone please help me understand why its failing? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't see any `'.'` following a `)` in the table definition.  Are you sure that is the entire code being executed?

Comment: All SQL statements in Teradata are terminated by semicolon: `... col8 BIGINT
);` And check if the 1st column is good for basing the NUPI on it.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, sorry about that. the "." following part is mentioned separately in the error portion. I was missing a ";" after the query, i added it and issue got resolved! Thanks for your comment